# Same path as both a system and normal include CMake

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, compiler-flags, dynamic-library

**Problem:**
When using the following `target_include_directories` call on the same path, CMake is overwriting the normal,`-I` flag with the `-isystem` flag.

**Call:**
`add_library(lib SHARED libSource.cpp)
target_include_directories(lib PUBLIC pathA)
target_include_directories(lib SYSTEM PUBLIC pathA)`

**Question:** How do I prevent CMake from overwriting the `-I` flag for `pathA`, so that it builds the object file with **both** flags and that in the `make VERBOSE=1` output I am able to see both the `-isystem pathA` and `-IpathA`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't understand what passing both `-isystem pathA` and `-I pathA` would do

Comment: From [gcc's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html): "If a standard system include directory, or a directory specified with `-isystem`, is also specified with `-I`, the `-I` option is ignored"

Comment: @Justin, okay good to know. Before moving to the CMake config, I had the same directory included as both a cppflag and an include flag in my makefile and it worked just fine. From the `verbose=1` output of the CMake config, I get two different sets of errors when I remove one or the other of the `target_include_directories` calls listed above. I am also passing the `-nostdlib` flag, which is why I need `pathA` to be passed with both the `-isystem` and `-I` flag.